# Yii CGridView Model Set Default Sorting Order

Tags: php, yii

My Yii CGridView Sorting is not working this way when

```
public function search() {
   $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
   $criteria->order = "member_id DESC";
```

When I click header menu in `CGridView` it is not working but when I remove

```
   $criteria->order = "member_id DESC";`
```

sorting is working fine. I want to show records by default `order by member_id desc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think problem is here

```
$criteria->order = "member_id DESC";
```

Just Remove this line and then add in

```
   return new CActiveDataProvider($this,array(               
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                        'defaultOrder'=>'member_id DESC',
                    ),
        ));
```

hope it will be help you.

Comment: posting a duplicate answer three hours later isn't honest

Comment: Hi, I have many models and gridviews in my project. Every model has created_date field. So I would like now that how can I override class `CActiveDataProvider` where I'll add `DESC Sort` condition so that it'll work for all my gridviews instead of adding condition in each gridview.

Comment: you can enhance CActiveDataProvider and create a new class in component folder, like `MyActiveDataProvider extend CActiveDataProvider { set order here}

Answer (score 10):

Remove this line `$criteria->order = "member_id DESC";`

Amend your return:

```
return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    'sort' => array(
        'defaultOrder' => 'member_id DESC',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 6):

**Use CActiveDataProvider:** In this class [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) you can find the property [defaultOrder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort#defaultOrder-detail) to set the defult visible order in your grid view with respect to your database table column name.

**defaultOrder:** defaultOrder is a property in CActiveDataProvider class. This property is belongs to the class [CSort](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort). As the class CActiveDataProvider inherited CSort, defaultOrder property became a property of CActiveDataProvider.

The syntax to do your task is

```
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('YourModel',
                    array(
                        'sort' => array('defaultOrder' => 'member_id DESC')
                    ));
```

Pass this $dataProvider to your view

```
    $this->render('YourView', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ));
```

As you want to presenting the results in CGridView

```
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'data-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),            
        'columns' => array(                
            'column1',
            'column2',
            'column3',
            array('class' => 'CButtonColumn'),
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Hi, I have many models and gridviews in my project. Every model has created_date field. So I would like now that how can I override class `CActiveDataProvider` where I'll add `DESC Sort` condition so that it'll work for all my gridviews instead of adding condition in each gridview.

Comment: $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' => 'data-grid',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,            
        'columns' => array(                
            'column1',
            'column2',
            'column3',
            array('class' => 'CButtonColumn'),
        ),
    ));